# data will not populate listview

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I'm having issues populating my listview. I thought I had modifed my XML and adapters accordingly but apparently not. When the activity is loaded the dialog pops up stating it's loading then the app force closes. If i remove the 3 lines of coding stating listview.setText(name) then it just loads all the items with the default text in my XML file. My code looks like this:

```
public class DisplayServiceActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ListView listOfServices;

    //JSONArrays?
    JSONArray directory;


    //JSON Node names
    private static String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static String TAG_NAME= "name";
    private static String TAG_DIRECTORY = "Categories";
    private final static String url= "API LINK HERE";
    JSONObject json;
jsonParser jParser = new jsonParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> directoryList;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.service);

    directoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Request request = new Request();
    request.execute();

    listOfServices = getListView(); //get builtin listView




    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("Home Service Categories");

    }
}// end of onCreate Method
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
    private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = 
            new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Getting your info real quick... Please wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);

        return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {          
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        String name = null;
        String id = null;
        dialog.dismiss();

        try {
            directory = s.getJSONArray("Categories");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< directory.length(); i++){;
        try {
            id = directory.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_ID);
            name = directory.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_NAME);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        displayCatList(id, name);

        }

    }

}

public void displayCatList(String id, String name){                 
    //create new HashMap
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //add each child node to HashMap key
    //map.put(TAG_ID, id);
    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

    //adding HashList to ArrarList
    directoryList.add(map);



    // set Adapter for ListView here
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            directoryList, 
            R.layout.list_item, 
            new String[] { name }, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1});



    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View  v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    TextView listName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listName);
    listName.setText(name);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

List_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="rubble rubble rubble"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="rubble rubble rubble"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which line throws the exception exactly? (line 158, hard to tell without the line numbers...)

Comment: line 158 is this:
 `listName.setText(name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Change display methods

```
      public void displayCatList(String id, String name){                 
      //create new HashMap
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //add each child node to HashMap key
    //map.put(TAG_ID, id);
    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

    //adding HashList to ArrarList
    directoryList.add(map);

    MySimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, directoryList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

// add folloowing class  in activity

```
  public class MySimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        listItems = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null) {
                  LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

          TextView listName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listName);

        listName.setText(listItems.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated it and now the rows are just staying the default text from the xml file.

Comment: You aren't telling the adapter to redraw when you want to refresh it.  You do this by calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: that isn't an option (using eclipse) and when I type it in it doesn't allow it (i tried to do this before posting on here).

Comment: Hello there is some modification in displayCat method and implements Adapter. I test this code and it work for me. If any help needed is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your view to R.layout.service.  But in displayCatList you're calling findViewById for a view in listitem.xml.  That won't work-  it isn't in your view.  If that text view is supposed to be in the list, you need to set it when the adaptor's getView is called.  Or let the simpleAdaptor do it for you.  If you don't want that to be part of the row, then don't add it in the listitem.xml

Comment: should I combine the list_item elements into service.xml? I replaced service.xml with list_item and it forced closed. I'm not exactly sure the code to remedy this situation.

Comment: list_item.xml should have only what you want to repeat for everything in your array.  If you don't want a new copy of it for each row, it should be in service.  If you do, it should be in list_item.  But you shouldn't be updaing anything in any row directly in your activity-  the adapter does that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really getting the hang of the adapter. I'm more use to object-c on iOS that is pretty straight forward. I do however want to update each individual row with the dynamic name variable.

Comment: So think of the ListView as a view with an infinite set of rows, that handles scrolling and decides what subset is on screen at any time.  It has its own internal MVC architecture.  The view is the xml file you use for the row.  The model is the data array-  in this case the directory list.  The controller is the adapter-  it can initialize the view for any position in the list by reading data from the model and doing all the processing needed.

Comment: When the listView scrolls, the listview and adapter take care of updating the rows on screen. So long as the model doesn't change, it will update everything fine.  When the model does change, you need to notify the adapter.  And since you're using a built in adapter, it should take care of everything for you-  it uses an assumed set of ids in the row xml to map data from the model to the view.

Comment: Actually, you may want to read up on how to make a custom adapter-  not that you need one, but it may be easier to understand what it's doing if you read up how it actually works under the covers.  I don't even bother using the built in adapters-  I find it easier to write the 5 lines of code I'd need myself and get the flexibility to easily change my UI.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at that. Thank you for your explanations :). Also I'e updated my original code and still the dynamic text isn't showing..

Answer (score 0):

Your `listName` is null, because he TextView `R.id.listName` is not in the main layout. To get the value of the TextView do something like this:-

```
LayoutInflator li = getLayoutInflator();
View listItems = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
// set Adapter for ListView here
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                directoryList, 
                listItems , 
                new String[] { id,name }, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });


        TextView listName = (TextView) listItems .findViewById(R.id.listName);
        Log.e("XML Variable", name);
        listName.setText(name);
```

Here what I've changed is I've inflated the `R.layout.list_item` in an view named listItems, and used it to find the TextView listName.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this code and it wants listItems to be an int, otherwise it won't compile. I updated my original post with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling the asynck task first which is handling everything including the setAdapter for listview and then again you are calling the setAdapter with directoryList which is blank as you have initialised after async task. Best solution is initialise you directoryList about asynctask call.

```
 directoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
 Request request = new Request();
    request.execute();
```

And then your whole code try this out. I think it will solve your problem...... 
I hope it works.

Comment: Dont set the adpater in the on create method let the async task handle try it I hope it works......

Comment: I removed the adapter in onCreate and now it loads the listView with the default info, not the dynamic text. I updated the code in the original post.

Comment: do one more thing put the setcontentview() just after the super() line.... Then check what it shows even if it shows default value check if your directoryList is getting filled or not by either Log.d size or all the items from the directoryList....

Comment: Using log.d directoryList contains [] in the onCreate right before the adapter it contains the full array of information:
`05-13 01:28:23.636: D/Test(16294): [{name=Glass Repair}, {name=Appliance Repair}, {name=Air Conditioning}, {name=Community Involvement}, {name=Electrical}, {name=Flooring}, {name=Heating Repair}, {name=Landscaping}, {name=Plumbing}, {name=Remodeling/Renovation}, {name=Window Coverings}]
`

Comment: I think you are trying to inflate a new view using simple in built adapter.I think the problem here is you are inflating a layout but you are unable to add that layout to the listView default layout. Why dont you use a CustomAdapter that will be really more convenient and all you problems will be solved.

Comment: are you referring to having it like this:
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.service);

  directoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

If so I already have it that way.

Comment: I'll start trying to figure out how to do that and get back to this thread.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html just go through this tutorial its best for customAdapter.....